# Null object reference in .onBackPressed()

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I have fatal exception in the method onBackPressed(): on a null object reference. 
How to handle the exception correctly?
My code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    List fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    BaseExampleFragment currentFragment = (BaseExampleFragment) fragments.get(fragments.size() - 1);

    if (fragments != null && !currentFragment.onActivityBackPress()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: *How to handle the exception correctly?* Fix it: 1. check what is null 2. do not use this null reference

Comment: @VishnuSP Do you see that I'm trying to process non-existent data? But there is no interception. Have you ever read the answer that you post and my question?

Comment: @Selvin look at my question more closely. I check there is a list of fragments. If it exists then I try to take a fragment. Everything works fine on the simulator, on most devices, but sometimes this error appears.

Comment: @Roman it does change anything ... you do not check if `getSupportFragmentManager()` returns null, `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();` returns null nor `fragments.get(fragments.size() - 1);` ... obviously one of this can be null **please read more closely the question which is pointed as duplicate it's all there**

Comment: @Roman Please try to find which object is null from the logs and try to handle it. It similar to NullPointerException.

Comment: @Selvin thanks for answer. I really did not understand what could be null there, because I did check in the list of fragments.

Answer (score 1):

it would be much easier if you also gave the stack trace.
However it is possible you are checking the wrong thing for null, change `fragments` to `currentFragment`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    List fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    BaseExampleFragment currentFragment = (BaseExampleFragment) fragments.get(fragments.size() - 1);

    if (currentFragment != null && !currentFragment.onActivityBackPress()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I realy do not understand why if there is a fragment, the current fragment does not exist. On the simulator, there is no mistake, only on devices sometimes there is this error. I get it from Fabric

Comment: maybe the list of fragments is null